# Where can I find a sample Service Inventory Blueprint?

Tags: service, soa

I am working on delivering a service inventory blueprint to a customer, and I would like to see a real-world example.  I have seen some very limited examples from Thomas Erl's books, but their depth and detail leave much to be desired.  Pointers or links, anyone?  Thanks!

Comment: delivering a service usually involves developing at several layers, what kind of examples are you searching for? please provide more details

Answer (score 1):

In case this is still sought after, a couple of examples online:
[

> [NCI Institute Enterprise Service Inventory Blueprint](https://wiki.nci.nih.gov/display/EAWiki/NCI+Enterprise+Services+Inventory+Blueprint)
>
> [WiseClouds Service Inventory Blueprint](http://rdschneider.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/service-inventory-blueprint.pdf)

Hope this helps.